# Is there a way to make AutoIt's WinWaitActive care about if a window is visible

Tags: windows, automation, autoit

My script is supposed to wait for the "Select File" dialog of IE to appear, then make it go away and replace it with a custom select file interface. I've gotten it all working, but there is one thing nagging me. The code is as following:

```
WinWaitActive("Select File")
WinSetState("Select File", "", @SW_HIDE)
```

The problem seems to be that the "Select File" dialog is (invisibly) created by IE, made active, *then* made visible. It's a basic threading problem really:

In some cases, IE makes the dialog active (but not visible yet!). My script picks that up, *Hides* the dialog (which actually is already hidden), and then IE makes the dialog visible which results in a visible dialog(!).

Is there any option I can set which makes the WinWaitActive command also wait for the window the be visible, not just active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the function below to know if the window is visible.

```
Func IsWindowVisible($handle)
    If BitAnd(WinGetState($handle), 2) Then 
        Return 1
    Else
        Return 0
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

then you can use a loop like this to do what you want:

```
While 1
    If IsWindowVisible(FindWindow("Select File", "")) Then ; I'm not sure about FindWindow syntax
        WinSetState("Select File", "", @SW_HIDE)
        Break
    Else
        Sleep (1000)
    EndIf
EndWhile
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually used the following code (\n where there should be a \n):
`While not BitAND(WinGetState("Select File"), 2)\n Sleep(250)\n WEnd`